# Lxml.html Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, lxml

Я не понимаю, как сделать нормальный вывод тега

```
URL = 'https://imgur.com/iTZUi2Q'# + random_e(7)
page = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
parsed_body = html.document_fromstring(page.text)
image = parsed_body.xpath('//div')
```

Вывод:

```
[<Element div at 0x35fcf90>, <Element div at 0x35fcfc0>, <Element div at 0x3642030>, <Element div at 0x3642060>]
```

А хотелось по типу:

```
['<div id="test">',.....]
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `tostring`, пример:

```
from lxml import html

...

def to_str(root):
    return html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode')

images = parsed_body.xpath('//div')

print([to_str(node) for node in images])
```

---

**PS.**

Наглядный пример использования `tostring`:

[Для парсинга html](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/938c15184911c72309d233339d80b9634d469f30/lxml__xml.etree__examples/parse_html.py):

```
from lxml import html
root = html.fromstring('<p>Hello<br>world!</p><br>')

print(html.tostring(root))                      # b'<div><p>Hello<br>world!</p><br></div>'
print(html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))  # <div><p>Hello<br>world!</p><br></div>
print(html.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))   # b'<div>\n<p>Hello<br>world!</p>\n<br>\n</div>\n'
print(html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
# <div>
# <p>Hello<br>world!</p>
# <br>
# </div>
```

[Для парсинга xml](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/938c15184911c72309d233339d80b9634d469f30/lxml__xml.etree__examples/parse_xml.py):

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring('<a><b>Hello</b><c>world!</c></a>')

print(etree.tostring(root))                      # b'<a><b>Hello</b><c>world!</c></a>'
print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))  # <a><b>Hello</b><c>world!</c></a>
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))   # b'<a>\n  <b>Hello</b>\n  <c>world!</c>\n</a>\n'
print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
# <a>
#   <b>Hello</b>
#   <c>world!</c>
# </a>
```